# Substitute a row with unequal subsets of Pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy, group-by

Suppose I have the dataframe (df1),

| ID | customer_only | city | state |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | N | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | Y | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | A | B |
| 2 | N | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | Y | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 | C | D |
| 2 | 0 | E | F |
| 3 | N | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | Y | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 | G | H |

The expected output is as follows.

| ID | customer_only | city | state |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | N | A | B |
| 1 | Y | A | B |
| 2 | N | C | D |
| 2 | N | E | F |
| 2 | Y | C | D |
| 2 | Y | E | F |
| 3 | N | G | H |
| 3 | Y | G | H |

Here is my code.

1. Fill state and city columns with `np.NaN`

   ```
   data = {
       "ID": [1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3],
       "customer_only": ['N','Y',0,'N','Y',0,0,'N','Y',0],
       "city": [0,0,'A',0,0,'C','E',0,0,'G'],
       "state": [0,0,'B',0,0,'D','F',0,0,'H']}

   df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)

   df1[['city', 'state']] = df1[['city', 'state']].replace(0, np.NaN)
   ```
2. I used `bfill()` to fill the previous NaN(s) with the values of city and state in the row with customer_only=0.

   ```
   df1[['city', 'state']] = df1[['city', 'state']].bfill()
   ```
3. However, for ID=2, `bfill()` does not give the expected output. I also used `groupby()`, but it cannot reshape the dimensions of ID=2 rows.

Any suggestions?

Comment: *"in the row with customer_only=0"* - Eh? That code doesn't even touch `customer_only`. Is that what you want to ask? We don't do suggestions per se, so please check out [ask] and [edit] to clarify.

Comment: If you didn't have multiple 0s per group a `bfill` would be a good approach, here you need to `merge` to create the combinations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can slice the 0/non-0 rows separately and [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
# identify non-0 rows (use the correct type)
m = df['customer_only'].ne(0)

# pick the non-0 rows, merge with the 0s on ID
out = (df.loc[m, ['ID', 'customer_only']]
       .merge(df.loc[~m, ['ID', 'city', 'state']], on='ID')
      )
```

Output:

```
   ID customer_only city state
0   1             N    A     B
1   1             Y    A     B
2   2             N    C     D
3   2             N    E     F
4   2             Y    C     D
5   2             Y    E     F
6   3             N    G     H
7   3             Y    G     H
```